# ReferenceError: inCart is not defined in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a shopping cart when I started coding I am getting `ReferenceError: inCart is not defined` error:

> ```
> ReferenceError: inCart is not defined
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Win10\nodex\app.js:20:1)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
>     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
> ```

```js
'use strict';
const config = require('config');
class Cart {
  constructor() {
    this.data = {};
    this.data.items = [];
    this.data.totals = 0;
    this.data.formattedTotals = '';
  }
}
module.exports = new Cart();
inCart(productID = 0) {
  let found = false;
  this.data.items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.id === productID) {
      found = true;
    }
  });
  return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the function using the function keyword

```
function inCart(productID = 0) {}
```

Or using the arrow function syntax as follows

```
const inCart = (productId=0) => {};
```

Please keep in mind that functions defined through function expressions must be defined before the call. Function expressions are functions that you defined through a variable keyword as follows:

```
var inCart = function(productID = 0){}
```

or

```
let inCart = (productID=0) => {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using strict mode `'use strict'`. When using strict mode, you cannot use undeclared variables, this will raise a Reference error.
You must declare a function using the `function` keyword as shown above.